# /questions/add of StackExchange app gives nonsense response

Tags: support

When I run https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question from the doc page and from my app. The response is sometimes nonsense:

```
{
    "error_id": 407,
    "error_message": "You cannot perform this action for another 48 seconds",
    "error_name": "write_failed"
}
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably having this error because of throttles (most likely per-method throttles) that are used to prevent abusive usage. Have a look at [related documentation page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) in order to learn more about throttles. Normally you should wait for a specified period which is returned in the `backoff` field of the previous response.

Comment: Is this the `backoff` returned in the previous response that tells to wait for a specified time?

Comment: @amitjha yes it should be returned in the previous response. Changed the answer to reflect that.