# "backoff" missing when updating questions

Tags: bug

I updated a couple of questions with the [questions/{id}/edit](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question) method and got the following error:

```
{
    "error_id": 407,
    "error_message": "You cannot perform this action for another 14 seconds",
    "error_name": "write_failed"
}
```

The response to the previous edit request did **not** contain a `backoff` property as described in https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Is this a bug?

---

I can work around this by waiting 4 seconds between edit requests.

Comment: Probably not a bug as it wasn't the *API* that was throttling you.  It was probably one of the standard "anti spam" limits that apply to all users.  ... I think this is a dupe but don't have time to look at the moment.

Comment: There is https://stackapps.com/q/6409/46140 but that's only telling about ... `backoff`.

Comment: There are often dupes on other sites, mainly MSE and metaSO.

Comment: Didn't find any there about `write_failed` that are relevant.

Comment: Okay.  Maybe not a dupe (I know this issue has come up)?  Don't have time to do more now.  Anywho, not the API that's the limit here.

Answer (score 1):

In the [throttle doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) you linked to it says:

> Every application is subject to an IP based concurrent request throttle. If a single IP is making more than 30 requests a second, new requests will be dropped. The exact ban period is subject to change, but will be on the order of 30 seconds to a few minutes typically.

And it is highly likely that you see the IP throttle in effect and not the dynamic throttle. The IP based throttle is in effect on the [HA-Proxy](http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/08/26/1016491873/) but that article is from 2010 so I assume by now and by my own experience certain routes are more likely to get you IP banned then others. See [How many requests are too many?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249893/how-many-requests-are-too-many)  and [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/158100), specially the explanation about the Chat rate limit, which seems to work similar to the API.

Basically you have to design and code for two throttle cases

- The IP based throttle, kicks in at will
- The dynamic throttle, covered by the `backoff` parameter (assuming you haven't filtered it out)