# Can I use the Stack Exchange API to build a "GH Archive" like project?

Tags: discussion, api

I'm not sure if I can use Stack Exchange API to build a https://www.gharchive.org like project?

I studied [the API throttling documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you certainly can.

But given that you're only allowed 10,000 API calls each day, [assuming you have a key](https://stackapps.com/questions/8971/i-only-need-a-key-what-do-i-do), you can barely fetch each new post (question or answer) on a regular day. [These numbers show exactly that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1677142#graph). Beyond that you are subject to throttles and IP rate-limits. If you plan to use every 10,000 allowed calls, you can have a call every 8 seconds. Making calls at a higher rate makes no sense as you will run out of API quota before the end of the day.

Beware that the throttle guidance talks about both IP based and dynamic throttles. Those are different things and applied separately. See ["backoff" missing when updating questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/7373/backoff-missing-when-updating-questions/7691#7691) and [What's the relation between access_token, key, quota_max, and throttling?](https://stackapps.com/questions/9224) or search in the [rate-limit tag](https://stackapps.com/search?q=%5Brate-limit%5D++answers%3A1)

You might be better of to leverage the already available data sources for data-analysis, be it the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) (refreshed weekly) or the [Stack Exchange Data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (refreshed quarterly).